# ipython notebook can't open web browser

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

system:CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

python: 2.7.11

ipython:IPython 4.2.0

jupyter : 4.1.0

I tried to run IPython notebook. But after typing the command "ipython notebook", i found it didn't open the web browser, whereas still staying on the Linux like the picture below showing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdNDi.png)

Comment: have you tried with `ipython notebook --no-browser`?

Comment: @manetsus `--no-browser` is used to do not open a browser when starting the notebook. One basic question, do you have a web browser installed? You can use the `--browser` option to indicate Jupyter/IPython which browser to use as it seems the default is not found.

Comment: I haven't explained clear. My system is windows, and I used Xshell to connect cluster without root. So Can I install chrome browser in my account? and How? Thanks a lot!  Besides, when i add the parameter `--no-browser`, it was stuck and didn't move.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem with you before. I fixed it by adding a default browser in my ubuntu subsystem.

```
$ sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Then I using Xming X server to configure graphical application under my subsystem can be displayed using bash. To do that, simply install Xming, and then go to ~/.bashrc file add the following lines:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

After saving, you should be able to run firefox by typing:

```
$ firefox
```

Then, run

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

It should pop up a web browser and open jupyter notebook.